# How can I run a program as a root user when my Ubuntu 15.04 machine starts up?

Tags: scripting, startup

On Ubuntu 15.04 I have this file: **/usr/local/bin/myscript** (it's a script I made).

If I run this command under my account, it will do what I need it to do as a root user: **sudo /usr/local/bin/myscript**

I now want to make **/usr/local/bin/myscript** run on machine startup, but as a root user (as if I was running the sudo command but without having to type any password). How is this done on Ubuntu 15.04?

Comment: Do you want GUI password prompt for running script on starting machine or not?

Answer (score 16):

## And now, the systemd answer.

You're using Ubuntu version 15.  You have systemd.  `/etc/rc.local` is at best a backwards compatibility mechanism in systemd.  And as shown by the mess in the AskUbuntu question hyperlinked below, using it can go horribly wrong.  So make a proper systemd service unit.

You are creating a local, non-system non-package, service unit, so the unit file will be in `/etc/systemd/system/` which is where that type of units go.  Let us call it `/etc/systemd/system/myscript.service`.  It contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=user2580's script
Documentation=https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202698/

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myscript

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If your script forks "in order to dæmonize" then stop it from doing so.  That's completely unnecessary.

- Run `systemctl preset myscript.service` (as the superuser) to have it start automatically at bootstrap.
- Run `systemctl start myscript.service` (as the superuser) to manually start it right now.
- Run `systemctl status myscript.service` to see its status.

Note that this does not execute your script in a context where it will be able to talk to an X server.  It could be run before an X server is even started up.  But you don't mention any requirement for being an X client, nor for other complexities that bite novices like a `HOME` environment variable.  And those are subjects for other questions, in any case.  So I'll leave it at that.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200281/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2001).  ["Don't fork() in order to "put the dæmon into the background"."](https://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html#DoNotBackgroundise).  *Mistakes to avoid when designing Unix dæmon programs*.  Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: In case it needs to execute after other services (e.g., mounting a VM shared drive), one way is to set type=idle instead of type=simple.

Comment: I get `Failed to preset unit: File caps2esc.service: No such file or directory` when I try to run `systemctl preset caps2esc.service`. Am I missing something here? I'm on Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. 
Do you think that it's possible to run a specific command when the service stop is invoked?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add a line to call the script in `/etc/rc.local`.  This file is the last of the init scripts to be run.

Just make sure that `/etc/rc.local` is executable and owned by root.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **`gksudo`**:-

```
NAME
       gksu - GTK+ frontend for su and sudo


DESCRIPTION           
       gksu is a frontend to su and gksudo is a frontend to sudo.  Their primary purpose is to run graphical commands
       that need root without the need to run an X terminal emulator and using su directly.
```

- Open Startup Applications (System Settings > Startup Applications or `gnome-session-properties`).
- Add new Entry with following command (**`gksudo myscript`** or **`gksudo /usr/local/bin/myscript`**):-

[image: screenshiot]

Click Add and this script will run when you startup/login to desktop.

---

**Note:-** Make sure `gksu` is installed in order to work with `gksudo`. (you can install it by `sudo apt-get install gksu`)

---

Another way is to use Askpass program which works with `sudo -A`:-

```
-A, --askpass
                 Normally, if sudo requires a password, it will read it from the user's terminal.  If the -A
                 (askpass) option is specified, a (possibly graphical) helper program is executed to read the user's
                 password and output the password to the standard output.  If the SUDO_ASKPASS environment variable
                 is set, it specifies the path to the helper program.  Otherwise, if sudo.conf(5) contains a line
                 specifying the askpass program, that value will be used.  For example:

                     # Path to askpass helper program
                     Path askpass /usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass
```

Example I use `zenity` as askpass helper.